# Why was Anubis always shown in 'animal form'?

Tags: character, analysis, gods-of-egypt

All of the *Gods of Egypt* have a normal human appearance (beside that they are slightly taller). They can change forms to the animal-form which fits them most.
But Anubis is only shown in animal form all the time.

**Question**: Why didn't they show him in his human form or is there a reason why he always is in animal form?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything related to the script or any interview from people working on that movie. So, the following is only an opinion, and I'll try and back it up, but this must be an artistic choice, a logical choice, and maybe politically correct choice.

There's no real need to show Anubis with a human form. This god is often associated with its human body/jackal head. And death is not very often depicted as human-looking in arts.

> **Anubis firmly stands in pop culture as the jackal headed god**. Even those least knowledgable on Ancient Egyptian history are aware of his image; the famous black jackal headed man or full-bodied jackal laying proudly like a sphinx has been etched in the human psyche, and he remains a symbol of Egypt past and present. [Anubis in human form](https://egypt-museum.com/anubis-in-human-form/)

There are very few representations of Anubis as a human, unlike the other gods.

> An **extremely rare depiction of him in fully human form** was found in a chapel of Ramesses II in Abydos. [Anubis - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anubis)

> Death is frequently imagined as a personified force. Other beliefs hold that the spectre of death is only a psychopomp [1], a benevolent figure who serves to gently sever the last ties between the soul and the body, and to guide the deceased to the afterlife. [Deaths (personification)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_(personification))

> [1] Appearing frequently on funerary art, psychopomps have been depicted at different times and in different cultures as anthropomorphic entities, horses, deer, dogs, whip-poor-wills, ravens, crows, vultures, owls, sparrows, and cuckoos. [Psychopomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychopomp)

Hollywood needs diversity in movies, especially when representing cultures and histories. Some people complain about characters being (or not being) from one culture or background. And opinions vary. But what to do when you have a god, like Anubis, whose representative color is black? Do you ask a white actor to play it? Or a black actor? Or do you keep it simple and stick to the popular image of the human/jackal?

> Anubis was depicted in black, a color that symbolized regeneration, life, the soil of the Nile River, and the discoloration of the corpse after embalming.

Answer (score -1):

Why they kept Anubis in his animal form is not explicitly told in the movie. But I have some good ideas why they might have decided to play it out that way. **He is one of the most important gods in Ancient Egyptian mythology, dating back to the Old Kingdom of Ancient Egypt, roughly 2686–2181 BC.**

He had the head of a Jackal or Dog and the body of a human. Anubis was believed to have weighed the hearts of the dead against the feather of Ma’at to determine their worthiness for the afterlife. He was also responsible for guiding them through the underworld.

*It could be that they wanted to emphasize Anubis’ role as the god of the dead and protector of tombs and burial sites*.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question. How does him remaining in his animal form throughout the film emphasise *that specific aspect* of his duties?

Comment: Did you read the question? It was a simple one. "Why didn't they show him in his human form or is there a reason why he always is in animal form?" I haven't seen the film but I was giving them information that might be why he didn't change out of animal form.

Comment: Hmm. Let's have a look at this answer then. *"Why they kept Anubis in his animal form is not explicitly told in the movie* - You've not seen the movie, so it's not clear how you know this. "*I have some good ideas why they might have decided to play it out that way*" - You've only really advanced one idea ("*they wanted to emphasize Anubis’ role as the god of the dead"*) and you've offered no evidence to explain how him remaining an animal explains this.

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't just a forum to post interesting stuff. We're explicitly looking for definitive answers based on evidence.

Comment: I literally read a play by play of what the movie was about and based most of my answers off of that. It's not that hard to answer the question if you haven't seen the movie. He didn't get really specific about what he wanted. I think I answered it really well. There is no right answer because they don't come out and say it in the movie, so the next best thing is using you brain and speculating.

Comment: there are lots of other good sources that you could refer to, for example the movie script, source novels, deleted scenes, audio commentaries, interviews with the actors, making-of books, etc.

Comment: Point taken. I am not going to argue with you all afternoon. We can agree to disagree. Have a nice day!